# So I want the program to compute the grades inputted by the user when the user types in "N"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created an array named grades that prompts the user to input a grade then it will ask the user if he/she wants to input more grades. The user will just need to press Y to input a grade once more, then N, if the user wants to stop inputting grades and the program, should start computing the grades. But I'm stuck here.

This is my code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim inputhere, a, b As Integer
    Dim prompt As String
    a = 0
    Dim grades(a) As Integer

    Console.Write("Enter Grade: ")
    inputhere = Console.ReadLine()
    grades(0) = inputhere


    While True
        Console.Write("Enter Again [Y/N]: ")
        prompt = Console.ReadLine()
        If prompt = "Y" Then
            b = a + 1
            Console.Write("Enter Grade: ")
            inputhere = Console.ReadLine()
            grades(a) = inputhere
        ElseIf prompt = "N" Then
            grades(a) += inputhere / b
            Console.Write("Average: ")
        End If
    End While
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It8vr.jpg)

So what happens is that it doesn't compute the grade but continues to loop.

Comment: Try running your program using Debug in Visual Studio. Debug can help you quickly find software problems and fix them.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have any exit condition in your while. So either you force it or you change your loop condition

Here are the 2 options:

1. Add an `Exit While` in your computing block:

```vb
    While True
        ' ....
        If prompt = "Y" Then
            ' ....
        ElseIf prompt = "N" Then
            grades(a) += inputhere / b
            Console.Write("Average: ")
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
```

2. Change your while condition

```vb
    Dim keepAsking As Boolean
    keepAsking = True
    While keepAsking
        ' ....
        If prompt = "Y" Then
            ' ....
        ElseIf prompt = "N" Then
            grades(a) += inputhere / b
            Console.Write("Average: ")
            keepAsking = False
        End If
    End While
```

Comment: I think you have addressed just a part of the problems present in the question. But the main question is _Iwant the program to compute the grades inputted_

Comment: @Steve. If you think so but the post ends with "So what happens is that it doesn't compute the grade **but continues to loop**. And the op already computes the grades in its loop (even if the calculation is mathematically wrong)